# Firebase BigQuery data range

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've been directed to post any questions on Stack overflow from Google regarding BigQuery

I have an app linked to Firebase collecting a few custom events. This has been running since August 2019. I've linked my firebase project to Big Query (Sandbox)

I've run a query to get a breakdown of 2 events which works fine BUT only for the last 2 days. When I put in a date range from say 1st August 2019 to 1st April 2020, I get the exact same number. If I choose a date range prior to the last 2 days I get no results.

I believe that only the last 2 days worth of data is being linked across.

How do I get access to all the data I have in Firebase analytics in Big Query? Is this a Sandbox limitation?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Nicholas - I would love to help, but it's really hard to know what's happening with so few details. Can't reproduce.

Comment: Hi Felipe, appreciate your reply. I’ve been searching more and it would appear that BigQuery thinks I only implemented / linked it from 2 days ago (now longer as extra day’s have passed since I posted this). And anything before that is ‘historical’ data which I can’t transfer across. Fact is, I linked BigQuery several months ago, albeit not as far back as to when I wish to analyse data. So in essence, I basically want to have BigQuery access to data that is fully available on Firebase

Comment: Hi Felipe, as a follow up, I hope you see this. Is ether any way in which to access 'historical' data, specifically custom events in either BigQuery or Google analytics? I started collecting custom events via Firebase in July 2019, but only activated BigQuery and Google analytics later on. While I can access basic analytic date for the whole time, I can't get custom events. I need this data for a research paper. Is their a way? Thanks

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I would need you to update your question to include your query and more details of what you're trying to get. Your question still requires more information to know what you're doing.